# esri-leaflet query mutliple features (with setWhere)

Tags: leaflet, arcgis

We created a map in ArcGIS Online which is implemented with Leafletjs onto our website. Our aim is to query multiple features, but we don't know how, since we don't have much programming knowledge (geography students).

Specific problem: We have multiple dropdown menues concerning hiking trails and want to let users select for example the region and duration. But so far if the second selection is made, the choices from the previous selection are deleted and only the newest selection appeears.

Any suggestions? Thank you already! Corin & group

CODE:
one of the value definitions:

```
<div class="refinement_title">Choose a region</div>
  <div id="query" class="leaflet-bar">
<label>
  <select id="region_nr">
    <option value=''>Alle anwählen</option>
    <option value='1'>Berner Oberland</option>
    <option value='2'>Graubünden</option>
    <option value='3'>Innerschweiz</option>
    <option value='4'>Mittelland</option>
    <option value='5'>Ostschweiz</option>
    <option value='6'>Tessin</option>
    <option value='7'>Wallis</option>
    <option value='8'>Westschweiz</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

and the query looks like this:

```
  var region_nr = document.getElementById('region_nr');
  var difficulty = document.getElementById('difficulty');
  var time_nr = document.getElementById('time_nr');
  var season = document.getElementById('season');

  region_nr.addEventListener('change', function(){
    trails.setWhere('region_nr="'+region_nr.value+'"');
  });

  difficulty.addEventListener('change', function(){
trails.setWhere('difficulty="'+difficulty.value+'"');
  });
  time_nr.addEventListener('change', function(){
trails.setWhere('time_nr="'+time_nr.value+'"');
  });
  season.addEventListener('change', function(){
    trails.setWhere('season="'+season.value+'"');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example:

```js
trails.setWhere('difficulty IN (' + difficulty.value + ')');
```

You can also have multiple values separated by a `,` .